# Logarithm of absolute value of a holomorphic function harmonic?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic on some open domain $U\subset\hat{\mathbb{C}}=\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ and $f(z)\not=0$ for $z\in U$.

> Is it true that $z\mapsto \log(|f(z)|)$ is harmonic on $U$ ?

I guess the answer is yes and if that is true, how can I see that *without* a long and nasty calculation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, this is true.  If $f(z)$ is holomorphic and nonzero on $U$, then $1/f(z)$ and $f'(z)$ are also holomorphic, so $f'(z)/f(z)$ is holomorphic on $U$.  Therefore its integral $\log(|f(z)|) + i\arg(f(z))$ is holomorphic on any simply connected subdomain of $U$, so in particular $\log(|f(z)|)$ is harmonic everywhere on $U$.

Comment: Not so fast.  The derivative of $\log f(z)$ is $f'(z)/f(z)$, not $1/f(z)$.  Where's the $f'(z)$?

Comment: Whoops, you're absolutely right.  I'll fix that.

Answer (score 8):

Locally (but not necessarily globally), $\log f(z)$ is an analytic function because $\log$ is an analytic function.  The real part of $\log f(z)$ is $\log |f(z)|$, i.e. the polar representation of the complex number $w$ is  $w = r e^{i\theta}$ where $r = |w|$, and 
$\log w = \log r + i \theta$ so $\text{Re}(\log w) = \log r = \log |w|$.  The real part of an analytic function is harmonic.

Comment: Does this imply that this function is harmonic even if f=0 ? The harmonicity seems to be independent of branch.

Comment: At a point where $f(z)=0$, $\log(f)$ is not defined.  If $f$ is not identically $0$, $\log |f(z)|$ is harmonic in a deleted neighbourhood of such a point. Yes, any branch can be used for $\log(f)$.