# Choosing any branch cut, or some branch cut?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, holomorphic-functions, branch-cuts

In *An Introduction to Harmonic Analysis* by Katznelson I once stumbled upon this:
[image]

with the footnote

[image]

Here $D$ is the complex unit disk around $0$. $f$ is holomorphic with no zeros, and since $D$ is simply connected, we have that some branch $\log(f)$ is holomorphic as proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/211192). So now we can define $g(z)=(f(z))^\frac{p}{2}:=\exp(\frac{p}{2}\log(f(z)))$.

Now Katznelson claims that we can take any branch. I used to ignore this part, but the more I think about it, the more I get suspicious. What if the range of $f$ has a point in the branch cut? Then this should not work.

Am I wrong, or does he mean *some* branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ has no zero in the unit disk, then ANY branch of $\log f$ and of $f^\alpha$
is analytic. This follows from Monodromy Theorem (look in any course of Complex analysis). You actually cite this theorem when you write "simply connected".

(Branches of log differ only by an additive constant, if one is holomorphic then all are holomorphic). There is no such thing as a "branch cut":-)
It is just an artificial tool, not something associated with a function.
If you look at the proof of the monodromy theorem you see that there is no "branch cut" involved.

Comment: Interesting theorem. I read the wikipedia page after reading your answer and I believe I get the idea, but not the details. I believe I mixed branch and branch cut up (one is always chosen, the other not always).

Comment: So to restate my chaotic comment as a question: $D$ is simply connected, but how do we know that $f(D)$ is simply connected, since we need this to make sure that $f(D)$ is not some domain that encircles $0$ (so $\log$ won't even be continuous)?

Comment: You do not need this. If $D$ is simply connected, and $f(z)\neq 0$ in $D$, then branches of $\log f$ exist in $D$. Read Monodromy Theorem in your textbook.

Comment: We can find a small disk in $D$ such that $\log f$ is analytic. My problem lies within the assumption that we can analytically continue $\log f$ along every path within $D$. Is this a well-known fact? And how can we be sure that the phenomenon from my previous comment doesn't happen (the range of $f$ containing a circle around $0$ and thus preventing any continuous/holomorphic single-valued $\log$).

Comment: Analytic continuation on every path $\gamma$ is performed by the formula $\int_\gamma (f'(z)/f(z))dz.$

Comment: I get it now. Thank you so much.