# if $f$ is a holomorphic function, then $|f|^p$ is not harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove that if $f$ is a non-constant holomorphic function and has no zero points in an open domain $D$, then $|f|^p(p>0)$ is not harmonic in $D$.

I tried to use $\Delta=4 \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \bar{z} \partial z}$ but I found the calculation is too long. Is there any similar solution like [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211190/logarithm-of-absolute-value-of-a-holomorphic-function-harmonic%3F#comment-3846849)?

Comment: Show for $|f|^2$ first as that is $f\bar f$ so easy to apply laplacian; then since $f$ has no zeroes, it is locally $g^{2/p}$ for some holomorphic $g$ and apply above

Comment: @Conrad : Thank you for the comment. Would you mind explaining "it is locally $g^{2/p}$ for some holomorphic $g$" in detail? I didn't really understand the statement.

Comment: $f$ has no zeroes, so in a neighborhood of any $w \in D$ it has a holomorphic logarithm $h_w$ (it may not have a global logarithm as $1/z$ in the punctured unit disc shows), and then with $g_w=\exp (ph_w/2)$ one has $g_w^{2/p}=f$ so $f^p=g_w^2$

Comment: I see, thank you very much!